# Building RNNs on mixed sequential and non-sequential data

Tags: regression, neural-networks, recurrent-neural-network, sequence-analysis

I have a data set that is a bunch of windows, for each window I want to perform regression.  The windows themselves have four sequential features that span back about 24 time steps.  Additionally each window has some meta-data about that window that is relevant to the regression problem.

What I would like to do is apply an RNN to do the regression, without the metadata this is relatively straight forward to build.  However, I am not really sure what the best way to add non-sequential features to the RNN would be.  My initial thought is to add the non-sequential feature to a fully connected layer after the recurrent layers.  Is this a reasonable approach, or is there a more sensible way to approach this?

Comment: Good question - i wish someone had helped you to find an answer :-)

Comment: can you describe your task better? Perhaps give equations or be more concise. How does the input X look like? And how does the target Y look like?

Comment: cross-posted: https://qr.ae/TWnzf6